# How to install Windows Services Using Java?

Tags: c#, java, windows, service, installation

can anyone tell how a windows service can be programmatically installed using java?

I could use a code snippet for some "scientific article" in which I want to show the differences in solving this issue using C# and java ;)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used JavaService in past. You can also try the Jakarta's deamon http://commons.apache.org/daemon/

it seems the best.

Comment: I'd like to add an endorsement of Apache's procrun daemon. I am using it to start an OSGi runtime as a Windows service, and it has been pretty trouble-free, although there are some subtleties with Java6. It is a C++ service wrapper that attaches a Java JVM, configures it and starts it up.